# Why is Pytesseract not able to read these images?

Tags: ocr, python-tesseract, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am new to Pytesseract, and am using it for ANPR (automatic number plate recognition).

Here is the cropped grayscale images of the number plates I am feeding into Pytesseract:
[image: number_plate_1]

and

[image: number_plate_2]

but in the final result, Pytesseract is giving ?? for both:

[image: final_output]